# Generic approach to extract text from any HTML format using scrapy xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract the text from HTML page with has `<article>` node, but within this node, there is no standard format of nodes. I am able to extract the complete text within `<article>`, however my output is not the same as it shows on the HTML page. For example, below is the HTML is want to extract-

```
 <article>
        <div> This is first Paragraph </div>
        <div> This is second Paragraph 
            <div> This is third paragraph &nbsp
                <span> 3rd para continue </span> 
            </div> 
        </div>
 </article>
```

This is what i have in my code.

```
xxx = response.xpath("//article/div | //article/ul | //article/ol | //article/p")
content = ""
for eachLine in warningLetterlines:     
    tmp = eachLine.xpath('.//text()').extract()
content += "".join( i.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for i in tmp ) + "\n"
```

This code outputs as -

```
This is first paragraph
This is second paragraphThis is third paragraph3rd para continue
```

However, what i want is -

```
This is first paragraph
This is second paragraph 
This is third paragraph 3rd para continue
```

I have tried to add some custom logic to join the list with either "\n" or "" based on the inner node, but as i mention my HTML page is not in a common format so my code is breaking whenever it sees something new. I also thought of getting a list of node name and join it based on the name of the node ( like add "\n" for `<div>`/`<p>` and "" for `<span>`/`<b>` etc), but the length of these 2 list are not same. Following are some of the pages i am trying to scrap - (Notice that all 3 has a different html layout with-in `<article>` node.

https://www.fda.gov/ICECI/EnforcementActions/WarningLetters/2017/ucm572086.htm   https://www.fda.gov/ICECI/EnforcementActions/WarningLetters/2016/ucm503559.htm    https://www.fda.gov/ICECI/EnforcementActions/WarningLetters/2013/ucm376390.htm

I want to scrap these pages in the exact same text format how it is displaying on the page. I found a online html to text converter which gives me my desired output but i am not sure how to implement this by my own. 
Any approach / help please ? I am really stuck to this problem.

This is the online converter if you want to look at-

https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/html-to-text/

Comment: Try something like `concat(//article/div, "\n")` on your expression.

Comment: Should i add this in the xpath , can you please explain this function ?

Comment: Never mind, tried it and works only for the first match. Perhaps you could start by replacing `<div>&nbsp;</div>` with an uncommon character and parse the html after that. This XPath seems to get the text inside article tag `(//div[ancestor::article and not(.="&nbsp;")]/text() | //span[ancestor::article/div]/text())`.